# Как редактировать файлы в репозитории Github

Tags: git, github, jenkins, build, makefile

Я ответвился от одно репозитория, этот репозиторий содержит Shell-скрипты и make-файлы, сборка осуществляется в Jenkins. Но при этом на первом этапе основной скрипт выполняет 'make sync' для клонирования ресурсов еще нескольких репозиториев, в одном из них находится файл, который я хочу подправить и закомитить. Как мне его править, ведь Jenkins не видит этот файл при старте? И только после выполнения команды make sync он появляется в рабочей папке

Comment: Мне кажется тут Github непричем. А тема вопроса подразумевает редактирование на сайте Github

Comment: Не совсем тогда понятно, как редактировать на сайте Github, если в текущем виде он содержит не все файлы и директории, например, мне надо отредактировать dts файл в директории /u-boot/aarch/arm/dts - но сейчас ее нет, а после make sync она появляется. Jenkins же прогоняя скрипт сначала синхронизирует репозитории а потом собирает, вот как бы мне сказать ему, чтобы он мои отредактированные файлы учел при сборке. Если я например закоммичу созданные файлы из директории ./u-boot/aarch/arm/dts/file1.dts - то git status говорит, что 'up-to-date. nothing to commit'